# Highcharts Overlapping datetime Columns When Using addPoint

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to dynamically add data to a column chart with a datetime X-axis, using addPoint().

When I do this, in many cases the columns start to overlap with one another. Visually, it looks like the column widths aren't being updated properly.

Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/AkKqP/6/

Here's the corresponding code:

```
var d_t[ 10, 8, 13 ];
var cur=0;
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
          type: "column"
      },
      series: [{
          data: [ ]
      }],
      xAxis: {
          type: "datetime"
      }
  });
  // the button action
  $('#button').click(function() {
      var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
      var msec = Date.UTC( 2013, 3, d_t[cur] );
      chart.series[0].addPoint( [msec, 10] );
      cur++;
      cur = ( cur >= 4 ) ? 3 : cur;
  });
});
```

I've hard-coded four dates that cause the problem to appear.

If you click the Add point button 4 times, you'll see the data added and the odd behaviour of strange column widths (they seem too narrow) on the second add, and overlapping columns on the third and fourth add.

A workaround seems to be to give the dates to the chart in sorted order. Then, the chart draws properly. Or maybe this is required?

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I searched around and fiddled a bit and haven't been able to figure it out. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts, data for `xAxis` should be sorted ascending. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/AkKqP/8/